# PF Updating a TextInput according to Calendars

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am getting a starting date and an end day from the user and then counting the weekdays according to these values. These are my components:

```
<h:outputText  value="Starting Date: "/>
<p:calendar  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{aView.holidays.startingDate}">
   <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{aView.count}" update="count"/>
</p:calendar>
<h:outputText value="End Date: "/>
<p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{aView.holidays.endDate}">
   <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{aView.count}" update="count"/>
</p:calendar>
<h:outputText  value="Count of Days: "/>
<p:inputText id="count" value="#{aView.holidays.count}"/>
```

But it does not update the count. What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: is it a typo ? `<p:ajax listener="#{aView.count}" update="count"/>` is not inside the `<p:calendar  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="#{aView.holidays.startingDate}">` ??? cause there should be `</p:calendar>` after the `<p:ajax listener="#{aView.count}" update="count"/>`

Comment: yes, sorry it was a typo. I am correcting it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: is it inside a form ? are you sure you got no nested forms ? also is your `listener="#{aView.count}"` being called ?

Comment: it is inside a panel which is inside another panel which is inside a form :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the event on which the ajax listener gets executed!

So use

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{aView.count}" update="count"/>
```

instead of

```
<p:ajax listener="#{aView.count}" update="count"/>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! I already tried event="change" and also event="blur" but they didn't work. I also tried your solution it did not work either.